# Why do I get the following errors when I install themes and modules on the website locally running on my Mac?

Tags: installation

I'm just up and running and everything looks OK. Developing locally on a Mac with XAMPP, I have changed httpd.conf to suite my user and group, and FTP is OK. Now I want to install a new theme using "Install from a URL," but when I paste in the URL for my theme and click install, I get the following error:

> Warning: unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/update-cache-26f2422c/responsive-7.x-1.6.tar.gz) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in drupal_unlink() (line 2197 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/cashbacon/includes/file.inc).
>   Warning: unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/update-extraction-26f2422c/responsive/color/base.png) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in drupal_unlink() (line 2197 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/cashbacon/includes/file.inc).
>   Warning: unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/update-extraction-26f2422c/responsive/color/color-preview.png) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in drupal_unlink() (line 2197 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/cashbacon/includes/file.inc).
>   Warning: unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/update-extraction-26f2422c/responsive/color/color.inc) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in drupal_unlink() (line 2197 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/cashbacon/includes/file.inc).
>   Warning: unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/update-extraction-26f2422c/responsive/color/colors.css) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in drupal_unlink() (line 2197 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/cashbacon/includes/file.inc).
>   Warning: unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/update-extraction-26f2422c/responsive/color/preview.css) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in drupal_unlink() (line 2197 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/cashbacon/includes/file.inc).
>   Warning: rmdir(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/update-extraction-26f2422c/responsive/color) [function.rmdir]: Permission denied in drupal_rmdir() (line 2361 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/cashbacon/includes/file.inc).
>   Warning: unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/update-extraction-26f2422c/responsive/css/layout.css) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in drupal_unlink() (line 2197 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/cashbacon/includes/file.inc).
>   Warning: unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/update-extraction-26f2422c/responsive/css/responsive-style.css) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in drupal_unlink() (line 2197 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/cashbacon/includes/file.inc).
>   Warning: rmdir(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/update-extraction-26f2422c/responsive/css) [function.rmdir]: Permission denied in drupal_rmdir() (line 2361 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/cashbacon/includes/file.inc).
>   Warning: unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/update-extraction-26f2422c/responsive/favicon.ico) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in drupal_unlink() (line 2197 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/cashbacon/includes/file.inc).
>   Warning: unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/update-extraction-26f2422c/responsive/flexslider.css) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in drupal_unlink() (line 2197 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sandbox/cashbacon/includes/file.inc).

The file permissions are already set to 777.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **/admin/config/media/file-system**
and change the 'Temporary directory' from
/tmp to tmp